# What does "-04:00" in Google Calendar's Event.Datetime mean?

Tags: android, json, datetime, google-calendar-api

No matter how I change the time zone of an Event in Google Calendar, there's always a "-04:00" string trailing behind the Start and End's DateTime attribute when pulled using the Google Calendar API on Android. What I do is I create an Event from the web and view the results on an Android emulator.

For example:
If I create an Event whose time zone is in Toronto, Canada (FYI, which is the Calendar's time zone), it will show

```
"dateTime" : "2012-04-25T10:00:00.000-04:00",
```

If I change it to Taipei, Taiwan, it will show

```
"dateTime" : "2012-04-24T22:00:00.000-04:00",
```

The hours change automatically, which is great for implementation, but what does that "-04:00" stand for? (FYI, Toronto's time zone is "GMT-05:00")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the UTC offset, telling you which time zone the event's time is being expressed in. That's probably coming from the time zone setting of the calendar. Toronto is currently at [UTC-4:00](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=250), meaning it's four hours behind the [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) clock. So when you moved the event to Taipei, you kept it at the same local time (10 AM on the 25th), but the API expresses it in Toronto hours; i.e. the event will happen when it's 10 PM on the 24th in Toronto.

Toronto's time zone is GMT-5:00 (UTC and GMT are roughly equivalent) because without daylight savings, that's the offset. The API knows that Toronto is currently on daylight savings, though, and changes the offset accordingly.

It's also worth noting that this date/time format is [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and is the usual way of representing time in APIs.

Comment: Great answer! I just moved from Taiwan and I didn't know the effects of daylight saving! Also, thanks for the ISO, I was looking through RFC-2445 and could not dig out anything about it!